# Question about 3blue1brown's vector basis video

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I've just watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2LTAUO1TdA, I was wondering, if we have basis \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} When we take linear combinations of these basis' the columns correspond to both points in the x and y direction, i.e. the first column is the first vector that is 2 in the x direction and 1 in the y, but multiplying by vector \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \end{bmatrix} to give the linear system of equations \begin{bmatrix}2x-y\\x+y\end{bmatrix} the combination of the columns correspond to points in only one direction. Not sure if I've explained this well, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: To show that these do not only correspond to points in one direction take $x = 1, y = 0$ and then $x = 0, y  = 1$.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you explain it in a different way?

Comment: I'll give it a go. When we take a linear combination of x in the column picture is in two dimensions, in the row picture the x corresponds to one dimension.

Comment: It points in the direction $\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and it points in the direction $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and any combination inbetween

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to look at the matrix product in the following way, which some of the comments have basically sketched out:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
x
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+y
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This way, you can directly see that you still have a linear combination of the basis, but now the coefficients are $x$ and $y$ which are your unknowns.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry if I've misunderstood, I see how we have a linear combination in terms of x and y, I was wondering why x scales in two dimensions in the column picture, but only one in the row picture, is it meant to be like this, it doesn't seem consistent?